# Why won't my subsection appear correctly in the contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I need to show one subsubsection title in the main body of the text and another in the contents page. I have been using:

```
\subsubsection[contents title]{text title}
```

This had worked really well. Now one of the titles that I need in the contents has square brackets in and so gives me loads of error messages (I assume because the brackets are getting confused).

This is my minimum working example (`\subsubsection[$[\text{PtL}^5\text{(ppy)Cl}]^+$]{Title in text}` is the line causing the problem):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{1}
\subsubsection{Title in text}
\subsubsection[$[\text{PtL}^5\text{(ppy)Cl}]^+$]{Title in text}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help, sorry, I'm still relatively new to LaTeX!!

Comment: The first `]` is mistaken for the end of the optional argument. Use `\subsubsection[{$[\text{PtL}^5\text{(ppy)Cl}]^+$}]{Title in text}`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I'd tried a couple of things but not thought of brackets!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the attribute of your toc-text in curley  brackets in order to escape the `[]` command. I also inserted two commands which allow to show the subsubsection in your toc.

Please note that the command `\text{}` requires the package `mathtools` or alike.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % show also subsections in toc
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % show also subsections number in toc
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}
\section[test]{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{Title in text}
\subsubsection[{$[\text{PtL}^5\text{(ppy)Cl}]^+$}]{Title in text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To escap charaters add a \ befor it

Comment: Hi @y2k where should I escape what?